# No Sound in Xubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: sound, xubuntu

After an installation of Xubuntu 16.04.1, there's no sound at all.
I ran Alsamixer and checked the volume control, but it doesn't work.

Help much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure to use Pulse Audio, some music players find alternating sound, like sending your music out through HDMI or USB??

Comment: I did use Pulse Audio